# Add features to vector layer from WFS protocol read response

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I'm trying to add the features I get from a WFS query using the WFS protocol. But something doesn't work.

I have looked at other posts with people having similar problems, but their solution doesn't fit with my problem.

I have tried:

```
var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({ extractAttributes: true });
var features = gmlReader.read(evtResponse.responseText);
markerVectorLayer.addFeatures([features])
```

But then I receive a error:

```
TypeError: a is undefined

...b.push(d)}return b},parseFeature:function(a){for(var b="MultiPolygon Polygon Mul...

OpenLayers.2.13.1.js (line 380)`
```

When I use console.log to check the features it looks like a perfect FeatureCollection object.

If I loop the response and create polygons from the coordinate points it works, but the performance isn't functional.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since **gmlReader.read();** returns an array,  you should try this :

> markerVectorLayer.addFeatures(features);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly that doesnt do any difference. The same error is returned

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working example where I get the WFS features and add them to my vector layer:

```
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs',
        params: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'ne_10m_populated_places',
            featureNS: "http://openstreemap.org",
            bbox: '137.9109375,-54.98359375,155.4890625,-28.61640625'
            // using bbox for the request because the layer has a huge amount of features
        },
        //proxy: "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=",
        success: function (response) {
            var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({
                extractAttributes: true
            });
            var features = gmlReader.read(response.responseText);
            layer.addFeatures(features);

        }
    });
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/6115L481/